# Can't change separator (custom UIView) color upon selection in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I'm changing cell color upon click and I'm also changing the little custom separator at the bottom of the cell. However when I call `deselectRowAtIndexPath` the separator color is restored to the color it had before ignoring my change. Why is this happening, how do I accomplish this simple task?
Here's my code:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIView *separator = [cell viewWithTag:SEPARATOR];
separator.backgroundColor = _colorOrangeSelected;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue by subclassing `UITableViewCell` for my cells and overriding `setSelected` and `setHighlighted` methods. I guess native implementations just mess around with subviews and their backgrounds in a strange way that ignores their latest state.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

- drag a `UIImageView` to your cell and make it the separator. set the `image` and `HightLightImage` with two different image.

When selected cell, your custom cell will refresh subviews state automatically,but you have to prepare two images.

Answer (score 1):

UIView can not have a highlightedColor.
You can try following solution:
1. Using UIButton or UIImageView which can set highlightedColor or highlightedImage
2. Using drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    if (self.cellDevideLineColor != nil) {
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        [self.cellDevideLineColor set];
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, kCellLineHeight);

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, rect.size.height);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.width, rect.size.height);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}
```